# How to calculate MAUs in Firebase? Do I need BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

We're using Firebase for analytics on our mobile apps. But Firebase only appears to report on active users for 1, 7 and 28-day rolling periods. These are not the industry standard reporting metrics I'm looking for.

We also have a web app, where we're counting unique active users in Google Analytics, and we'd like to be able to compare (and combine) MAUs from our apps in firebase with web MAUs calculated in GA.

Is this possible without BigQuery?

If no, how much will BigQuery cost us?

It seems crazy to have to purchase BigQuery for this purpose alone. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is [it] possible [to get MAU] without BigQuery?

If the intervals in the analytics reports in the Firebase console don't suit your needs, you will have to roll your own. There is nothing built into Firebase for custom intervals. Most developers use BigQuery for such custom reporting, especially since this is quite easy to do by tweaking the default Data Studio template.

> If no, how much will BigQuery cost us?

If you have a look at the [BigQuery pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing), you'll see that this is quite involved making it hard to answer without knowing your exact amount of data. In general: if you store and process more data (i.e. have more users in your app or more reports), you will pay more. Luckily there is now a [BigQuery sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox), which allows you to process significant data without paying (even without entering a credit card). This gives you an option to try BigQuery, before committing to it.

Comment: So... are you saying BigQuery is the only way to extract events from Firebase?